Confusion About Physical Interpretation of Curl
So in this 3Blue1Brown video, at time 5:13, Mr. Sanderson gives physical interpretation of the curl of a vector field. He states that if you put a twig at a point in the vector field, with the twig's midpoint at the point, then the curl of the vector field at that point is a measure of how much that twig rotates around the point. In his example, if the top half of the twig is in a vector field with less magnitude than the bottom half, that would cause the twig to rotate, and the curl would be non-zero.
I understand the distinction between rotating around the midpoint and around the origin. However, $curl(F)$ for $F = <\frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}, 0>$ is $0$. At a point $r$ units away from the origin, the magnitude of the vector is $\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$; as $r$ increases, this decreases. Shouldn't this give the same effect as the example in the 3Blue1Brown video, since part of the twig would have the vector field slower than the other part if the twig is pointing towards the origin?


I bet there's a duplicate of this question on MathSE, but I can at least tell you this example is discussed at https://mathinsight.org/curl_subtleties

@MarkS. Thank you! This makes a lot more sense now.

See also PSE.
